# How to concatenate differently sized vectors in Julia?

Tags: arrays, vector, julia, concatenation

How can I concatenate arrays of different size with a "filler" value where the arrays don't line up?

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2]
```

And I would like:

```
[1 2 3
 1 2 missing]
```

Or

```
[1 2 3
 1 2 nothing]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why you would want to do that? (PS: none of the outputs you are asking for a valid Julia syntax)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the outputs. I have an array of mixed-length arrays that I would like to `show` in a matrix-like format. I wanted to combine them into a Matrix and then utilize the `show` method from `NamedArrays.jl`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way, using `rstack` which is "ragged stack". It always places arrays along one new dimension, thus given vectors, they form the columns of a matrix. (The original question may want the transpose of this result.)

```
julia> using LazyStack

julia> rstack(a, b; fill=missing)
3×2 Matrix{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 1  1
 2  2
 3   missing

julia> rstack(a, b, reverse(a), reverse(b); fill=NaN)
3×4 Matrix{Real}:
 1    1  3    2
 2    2  2    1
 3  NaN  1  NaN
```